# c# run cmd with argument and close it in finish

Tags: c#, cmd

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        startInfo.Arguments = "dir / s / b / o:n / A:D";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

I try to run cmd with argument but it not working...

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Step through it and find what all of the values are

Comment: I think you should change the arguments to "dir /s /b /o:n /A:D" (remove spaces "/ s" -> "/s" and so forth)

Comment: Why have you got spaces between the `/` and the switches?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not just using `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"c:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`?  It seems silly to execute an external process to get data that can easily be provided by classes built in to .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `spaces` between `/` and letters, so it looks like below:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/c dir /s /b /o:n /A:D";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

To wait for the process to end use `process.WaitForExit();`

Comment: "cmd.exe dir" will never exit, consider using "cmd.exe /c dir"

Comment: @enkryptor You are totally right. I edited my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

See `cmd.exe /?`, `cmd.exe` has no parameter `dir`.

The correct syntax will be `cmd.exe /c dir`. Also, you have extra space in your command line keys: "/ s" instead of "/s" and so on:

```
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/c dir /s /b /o:n /A:D";
```

Comment: do you know how get too the names of files?

Comment: Parsing `dir` output is generally a bad idea. Consider using `Directory.GetFiles()`.

Comment: i find it: dir /s /b /o:n

Comment: The `/A:D` parameter gets directory names only so I don't think `Directory.GetFiles()` will return those.   `Directory.GetDirectories()` is required here (although I prefer `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway the author asks for "names of files" specifically